# Which primary hub airport is the closest to the city centre?

Tags: transit, airports, cities

I don't like to stay for a long time at the airport on a transit, which is so boring. So I want to get out of the airport to enjoy the city if at all possible.

But many [major hubs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hub_airports) are so far away from the city centre that you won't get any decent chance to enjoy it.

For example, [from Incheon Airport to Seoul station, it takes you 43 minutes even on express rail](http://asiaenglish.visitkorea.or.kr/ena/GK/GK_EN_2_2_2_3.jsp). In Hong Kong's case, [it takes you 24 minutes from Hong Kong Airport to Hong Kong station](http://www.hongkongairport.com/eng/transport/to-from-airport/airport-express.html). It's not so bad, but it still takes about an hour on return-trip, after adding the average waiting time of a next train.

I don't like to enjoy the "around the airport" atmosphere; it's the "center" of the major city that I want (e.g. Gangnam or Myeongdong, not Incheon, Shibuya or Roppongi, not around Narita; and I assume international airports).

Is there any international hub that is close to the center of the city, possibly within 20 minutes? I want to make my travel plan by taking it into consideration, especially when it comes to a cheap layover ticket.

I don't mind a country or city as long as it is an international airport.

---

#### UPDATE

Sorry, in ***international airport***, I meant any airport where there is significant connecting traffic for international flights. I didn't mean just any airport that serves any international destination, which is [the technical definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_airport).

Comment: Tegel in Berlin comes to mind, also because it shows why this is uncommon: It was still there at the beginning of the 90s due to Berlin's peculiar history but is now supposed to close very soon to limit noise nuisances and to be replaced by a more spacious airport further away from the center. The same thing happened to Hong Kong and many other places years ago. It also has limited facilities for transit and fewer long-haul flights than Germany's major airports (Frankfurt, Munich...)

Comment: Lots of them: London City, Berlin Tegel, Warsaw Chopin come to mind.

Comment: Schiphol in Amsterdam is not too bad. Out of the city but excellent and rather cheap public transport connectcions make the city center very accessible.

Comment: I think there are way too many possible answers. I don't think 20 minutes is uncommon for smaller airportss, for instance Copenhagen airport is within 20 minutes of the center, but you probably won't find many trips with a layover in Copenhagen.

Comment: Reykjavik Airport (in contrast to Keflavik) is pretty much smack next to the city centre, and has a few international routes, so it may qualify.

Comment: LCY is a completely different beast, it's been designed to be close to the city center and certainly fits the definition of an 
"international" airport but it's not one of London's major airports, cannot support large jets and has very few long-haul flights (it did have one transatlantic flight IIRC).

Comment: With Heathrow Express it only takes 15 minutes to get from LHR to London Paddington.

Comment: @Henrik: Though it can be debatable how central Paddington is ...

Comment: Thank you for the comments. Hmmm.. I didn't know it is so uncommon, though all are in Europe. Then how about cities in Asia? Maybe I should narrow it down to more specific regions if it has so many potential answers...

Comment: Many of the world's major hub airports are situated some distance from the city because that is where land was available to build large, modern airports that can support a connecting hub (GRU, MXP, IAD, NRT, IAH, formerly YMX), whereas it was often unfeasible economically, politically, geologically, environmentally, etc. to expand an older, closer airport (CGH, LIN, DCA, HAN, HOU, YUL).

Comment: I thought I'd seen a nearly identical question before, but I can't seem to find it right now.

Comment: Taipei Songshan Airport is pretty much surrounded by the city of Taipei. It's no longer the main airport but is still an international airport in use.

Comment: Toronto City airport is about ten minutes **walk** from the downtown, with flights to New York and Washington.

Comment: Hmmm.. It seems that most of the airports mentioned here are **NOT** the main airport, which I assumed. In *international airport*, I meant the main airport for foreign travelers in the specific area/city (e.g. Narita, not Haneda; Incheon, not Gimpo; Pudong, not Hongqiao). I didn't know that *international airport* points to any airports that serve foreign flights. (And that's why I said *"and I assume international airports"*). Sorry, my bad...

Comment: BOS is just a few minutes away from Downtown Crossing.

Comment: LKE (Lake Union in Seattle) has a seaplane to Victoria, BC, Canada so it's international. The C Line rapid bus takes you downtown less than ten minutes.

Comment: @Blaszard In Europe almost every airport is an international airport. The miniature airport near my parents' house (BOH) has no domestic flights at all, and is less than twenty minutes from the town centre by bus. But that's probably not the kind of airport you are thinking of. You may want to use the words "primary hub airport" instead.

Comment: I edited your post to limit the question to major international connecting hubs, which is more answerable. Of course, please feel to roll back if I have not represented you correctly.

Comment: @Relaxed Getting to AMS might be cheaper than some other European capitals' airports, but having to pay a fee for using a MasterCard in a ticket machine made me feel like I was on Ryanair's website :-(.

Comment: The change to connecting hubs makes a difference. I was going to nominate San Diego International Airport.

Comment: @pnuts There is a €1 fee to use a credit card at the machine and a €3.5 fee if you buy a ticket at the counter.

Comment: El prat INTL (LELB), Barcelona, is barely 20min (and 2,9€) by metro from the city center, 35 if it's a very busy day.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Toronto City Airport](https://www.portstoronto.com/airport.aspx) has regular scheduled flights to Washington DC and New York, and is literally 25 minutes **walk** from the CN Tower, the unquestionable centre of downtown Toronto. A substantial chunk of that 25 minutes is getting out of the airport. The airport doesn't have a direct transit link to the city.

After that there's a big tie at 13-15 minutes (source: Google Maps, public transit time, directions destination in parentheses).

There are probably many other airports with similar travel times from their city centers; this is a community wiki answer, so other people can expand it with other airports.

- Boston (from the airport to the "Boston" Google Maps marker): 13 minutes
- Amsterdam (from the airport to Amsterdam Centraal): 14 minutes
- Copenhagen (Copenhagen C): 14 minutes
- Sydney (Central): 14 minutes
- London Heathrow (Paddington): 15 minutes
- Tokyo Haneda (Hamamatsucho station): 14 minutes
- [Zurich](https://www.zuerich.com/en/visit/to-and-from-the-airport) (Downtown): 10 minutes
- San Diego: 10 minutes by local bus.

Comment: I think the only way this question should stay open is if it becomes a CW. The answers are endless

Comment: That was my thought; in cases like this where the answer to a question seeking a superlative is a many-way draw, there are just too many correct answers otherwise.

Comment: Is Toronto City Airport a "primary hub" per the question's title?

Answer (score 6):

The airport in [**Eilat, Israel**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eilat_Airport) is not just close to the city, it's *in* the city.  The terminal entrance is only ~500m from the beach and many hotels: https://goo.gl/maps/Znhsv8FNzBT2

That said, it's primarily a domestic hub, although it does serve some charter flights, and it's scheduled to be replaced next year by a [new airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramon_Airport).  Visit while you still have a chance!

But as far as major international airports go, it's hard to beat [**Sydney**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sydney_Airport), which is just [13 minutes from Central station](https://goo.gl/maps/1fyBAfzzpo82).  (To the international terminal, that is, the domestic terminal is just 10 min away!)  And yes, Central really is quite central, although you can sit in the train for a few more minutes to get to Circular Quay and see the Opera House if you want.

Comment: Very true. Indeed, the airport beacon light for the Eilat airport is actually on top of a neighboring hotel building, presumably due to the amount of stuff built up right along the perimeter of the airport. I watched arrivals and departures for a while from my hotel balcony there. Most of the runway was in view.

Answer (score 2):

Frankfurt is not too bad. Less than 15 minutes by local train which is very reliable on runs every 10-15 minutes or so.

Downside: it's a huge airport. It's likely going to take a you a lot longer getting from your gate to the train station than the actual train ride. On an international layover you also have to go through immigration and customs on the way out and through security on the way back in.

Answer (score 1):

I think Dubai Airport wins this one. It is located in the city itself (technically the area is called Diera); and is only 6 minutes away (3.3 kilometers) to the nearest shopping center / mall.

Dubai Mall (Burj Khalifa) is 14 minutes.
Mall of the Emirates (with the indoor ski area) 23 minutes (by taxi).

Dubai itself is a very small place, so nothing is too far from the airport. There is a left luggage facility at Dubai and the metro runs regularly (except on Fridays, where it has a delayed schedule). Taxis are plentiful as well.